# Using python to connect to secure websocket

Tags: python-2.7, websocket, ssl-certificate

I am trying to test the functionality of a server via secure websocket. I have written a client which connects fine via a regular connection, but I cannot seem to connect via WSS. Here is my function to connect via WSS:

```
def connectWSS(self, certCAFile, certFile, keyFile):
    self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(self._wss_url, on_message = 
    self.on_message, on_error = self.on_error, on_close = self.on_close)
    self.ws.on_open = self.on_open

    socketOptions = {"ca_certs": certCAFile, "keyfile": keyFile, 
    "certfile": certFile}

    def run(*args):
        print "Starting..."
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.info("Connecting to websocket")
        self.ws.run_forever(sslopt=socketOptions)

    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())
```

I realize that I can just add

```
"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE
```

to the sslopt field but I want to connect via WSS using the certificates to verify that the server is actually checking them. The problem that I am running into is when it prompt me for

```
Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

When I entered my passphrase I am getting the following error:

```
EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

I am using self signed certificates for both the server and the client, so I generated the certificates myself using openssl. Is this an issue with my certificates or am I missing something in my code? I am quite new to this secure websocket stuff so if anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your certificate. 
Are you using FQDN or IP? You should use FQDN I think cause it will check hostname.
[You can check more explanation here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SSL)

Comment: But what if there's an option on the server side that, if enabled, requests the certificates from the client's side? How can i provide a certificate if that's the case? 

In the code above, I am providing a certificate/Key/CACert file as the ssl option. It seems to have an effect because if I put an invalid path then it complains about it

`socketOptions = {"ca_certs": "invalid.path", "keyfile": "invalid.path", "certfile": "invalid.path"}`

Comment: Yes, you're right. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884704/how-to-set-find-the-ca-certs-argument-in-python-ssl-wrap-socket. Thus you can trust even a self-signed certificate.